# .bat file behaves wrong from command line

Tags: internet-explorer, command-line, batch-file, browser

I have a .bat file that simply opens up two different browsers and points them to unique links. After it opens up the first browser, it waits a few seconds, then opens up the second browser. What I expect to happen is that the second browser's window will automatically be focused and active. This behavior only happens when I click on the .bat icon in windows.

When I run the .bat file from the command line, the second browser window opens, but in the background. This *only* happens when the first browser is IE - for some reason it doesn't want to relinquish window focus.

I have tried using flags like /max to make sure the browser is focused but that doesn't help in bringing the window to focus.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Here is the .bat file:

```
@echo off
:: start IE
start iexplore  http://localhost:9080/tests/test_getLink.html
:: Wait ~3 seconds 
@ping 127.0.0.1 -n 4
:: start FF
start firefox -new-window http://localhost:9080/tests/containerTwoWayForm.html?robot=active
```

(the IE page polls the server for a link and is in a "waiting" state when firefox opens. I Thought this might contribute to the behavior but I don't understand why it runs differently from command line vs just clicking.)

I have made sure that only IE as the first browser causes this behavior. Also, it doesn't matter what browser the second on is (chrome, ie, ff.)

I have also tried creating a second batch file to start the second browser and calling it from the first .bat, but that didn't help.

Thanks for any tips

Comment: This works for me on Windows XP, both by double-clicking the batch file and by running it from the command line.  (IE6 and FF 3.6.8)

Comment: Works for me, both from the command line and when double-clicking the batch from Explorer. Windows 7 here. Used IE and Chrome.

Comment: Work for me too on Windows XP.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot fellas for testing this on your own machines. I had a few friends around here try it out and apparently my box is the only one with problems...
Anyway I guess I'm going to ignore this issue for now and just not start from the command line. Not really a good solution but...it wasn't really a great question in the first place.
Thanks again guys!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because of the explorer version? Have you tried reinstalling it?
The script works for me also on Win XP SP3, IE7.