# Python script is behaving differently when run through batch file and cmd line

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a Python script which needs to be run with a batch file, but I've been using cmd to test it. When run through cmd, it works fine.  However, the script seems to behave differently when run through the batch file. I've isolated the section of code which seems to be the problem:

```
CRFOLDER = "some path to all my files"

isReady = False
os.startfile(os.path.join(CRFOLDER,"CLogger.exe"))

while not isReady:

    try:
        open(os.path.join(CRFOLDER,"CRPYLog.py"))
        isReady = True
    except:
        print "Not ready yet"
        time.sleep(0.25)

import CRPYLog as PyLog
```

This code calls an executable which creates a Python file, which I then import (if you're curious about the reason, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20577038/how-do-i-preserve-literals-when-passing-from-python-to-c-and-back-to-python)).  As I said, this works fine when run through cmd.  However, when I use the batch file, the `while` loop runs infinitely (or at least for 2 minutes, when run through cmd it hits the `except` just once).  This is weird.  I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112711/same-bat-file-behaving-differently-when-called-from-desktop-or-from-within-a-pro), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11022902/windows-bat-file-behave-differently-when-executed-from-command-window-and-by-do), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521583/bat-file-behaves-wrong-from-command-line) question with no luck.  The batch file is below.

```
start Y:\Admin\Anaconda\python.exe "Y:\Projects\Advent - Overhead Projects\Copy - ADV001 - CR Records Management - Copy\Python\CRWizard.py"
```

I've tried pasting that exact command into cmd and it worked fine, but the batch file does not.  Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `CRFOLDER`?  Is it pointing to the same location in both cases (batch file and run directly)?

Comment: What is CRFOLDER value for those two runs? For what reason you use startfile instead of for example `subprocess.call`?

Comment: I've updated the question, ```CRFOLDER``` is the path to where all my files live.  I had it print the value of ```os.path.join(CRFOLDER,"clogger.exe")``` and ```os.path.join(CRFOLDER,"CRPYLog.py")```, they both appeared to be correct

Comment: @alko, I assumed ```startfile``` was the cleanest way to open files in their default programs, but I doubt there's anything holy about it

Comment: can your `CLogger.exe` log absolute location of created file?

Comment: @latheiere, what do you mean by "log in"?

Comment: @latheiere, It should make it in the same directory as the executable (which is ```CRFOLDER```), however, it is making it in the same directory as the batch file... Good catch, write up an answer real quick so I can accept it.

Comment: Make sure any backslash path separators in the `CRFOLDER` string are doubled or prefix the string with an `r` like this `CRFOLDER = r"Y:\some path to\all my\files"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, your batch file is running excutable with windows native call (`os.startfile`), and hence sets some defaults (current folder), forcing executable to create resulting file in folder that differs from expected `CRFOLDER`.

I suggest you to specify excplicetely in which foder you need this `.py` file to be created, for example, to be a flexible solution, as a paramether to executable.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to type the **start** command for that. See [this](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/start.php). Just remove the start command.

```
Y:\Admin\Anaconda\python.exe "Y:\Projects\Advent - Overhead Projects\Copy - ADV001 - CR Records Management - Copy\Python\CRWizard.py"
```